# put file contents into array and update the data keeping the order

Tags: php, arrays

I got a file called: test

In this file we got strings like:

- apples
- cars

I want to be able to edit the data: Cars while keeping the line breaks.
If i edit array[1] it pushes them all together!.

So i want to change cars to like vans while keeping the file order in the end? I then get:

- applesvans

My code:

```
$linesvol = file_get_contents('/srv/test');
$playlists = explode("\n", $linesvol);
$playlists[1] = "vans\n";
file_put_contents('/srv/test', implode($playlists));
```

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Comment: Sorry, was waiting on the time to allow me to accept an answer but then forgot all about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file()` and preserve the line endings:

```
$playlists = file('/srv/test');
$playlists[1] = "vans\n";
file_put_contents('/srv/test', implode($playlists));
```

Or implode on line endings:

```
$playlists = file('/srv/test', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$playlists[1] = "vans";
file_put_contents('/srv/test', implode("\n", $playlists));
```

**Note**: If you are viewing this in some Windows applications you will not see newlines with `\n`, you need `\r\n`. Obviously, if you are viewing in a browser then you need `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the implode () to include line breaks.

Change from:

```
implode($playlists)
```

to:

```
implode("\n", $playlists)
```

Comment: bla bla bla... Neat.. :D

Comment: Thanks! New to arrays, decided to make use of file space. Im getting there though! Cheers!